# Import all vue js components in a single file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to import multiple Vuejs components to a legacy project.

Currently, I have included the following script in my website header:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js">
```

and a component file ( I would like to separate each component in a different file )

```
<script type="module" src="comp1.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="comp2.js"></script>
```

It does work, but I want to have **one JS file** that will import all other components so I can point to it in my HTML to a single JS file.

Any idea?

Comment: Add a bundler, ie webpack, no other way.

Comment: @Slim I tried to "add" vue js project to my legacy codebase, but it works as a SPA within one tag -  `<div id=app></div>`. I need to use the components inside the vue project.

Comment: I understood your case and you don't need to use vue-cli for the setup. Simply install webpack and import all your files into one file using `import` or `require.context` from webpack. The use webpack to compile them into one file that shall be referenced in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder for your bundler - `frontend-dev` for example.

```sh
$ cd frontend-dev
$ npm init
```

add the following dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
```

```sh
$ npm install
```

Create `webpack.config.js` with the following minimal configs:

```
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  output: {
      path: p('../public'), // where to create bundles files
      publicPath: '/public/', // public path to the created files
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  },
};

/**
 * Path.resolve alias curried with current directory (__dirname)
 * as first parameter
 */
function p(){
  return path.resolve(__dirname, ...arguments)
}
```

In `frontend-dev` create folder `src` and `index.js` in it:

```
// index.js
import '../../comp1.js'
import '../../comp2.js'
```

Add `"build": "webpack"` command in scripts section in `package.json` and run `npm run build` to see you bundled.js file in the specified public dir.

You can use `require.context` to import all files in a directory see [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext).

Comment: Thanks, what is the benefit of using babel / webpack.config.js here? I managed to build the app using "npx build" without the webpack config file.

Comment: Well, webpack is just an example of a bundler, that knows how to deal with imports. You are free to use the one you like the most :)